# How to compress Video data while taking video from camera?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any way to compress the video data while taking from camera ? There is huge difference in video data bytes from taking camera and from photo library.I want to reduce some memory while taking video from camera. Is any way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug report with Apple on this matter, you could do the same, seems the more reports from developers the faster they fix things up.
No matter what videoQuality level you set on the UIImagePickerController, it always defaults to High when recording from the camera. Videos chosen from the user library respect your choice and compress really well with the hardware H.264 encoder present on the 3GS and up.

Comment: Sounds good. I try it on apple.com but not able to find exact where need to submit form. Any link ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFMpeg](http://FFMpeg.org) to get video directly from camera, compress it and store it to a file.
Also FFMpeg is a standalone console application, and it doesn't need any other dlls.

Of course, this isn't objective-c, but it can be very useful in your case.